# Qual a definição de cada combinação de Seletores css

Tags: css

Os arquivos .css que são usados seguem um padrão:

```
seletor{
atributo: valor
}
```

A parte dos atributos e valores eu entendo, porém em alguns exemplos vejo estes seletores são sendo separados com ',' ou com um '.' na frente ou um '#'. Como nos exemplos:

```
 .s1{}
 #s1{}
 s1 s2{}
 s1,s2{}
 s1 *{}
 s1{}
.s1 a:link{}
```

Estes são alguns exemplos, qual a diferença de ambos para eu saber como trabalhar o ideal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quando se coloca um `.` na frente, significa que você está selecionando uma classe de um elemento `<div class="minhaClasse">` no css eu selecionaria ele com `.minhaClasse {}`.

Quando se coloca um `#` na frente, significa que você está selecionando uma ID de um elemento `<div id="minhaId">` no css ficaria `#minhaId {}`

Quando se tem 2 seletores seguidos como `e1 e2` significa hierarquia, ele selecionara todo elemento dois que se encontra dentro do elemento 1

```
<div class="elemento1">
    <div class="elemento2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Ai o css ficaria: `.elemento1 .elemento2 {}`

Quando os elementos são separados por vírgula, significa que você está declarando para os dois elementos

```
<div class="elemento1"></div>
<div class="elemento2"></div>
```

Então o css ficaria: `elemento1, elemento2 {}` e o que for declarado será interpretado para ambos os elementos.

Quando se usa o `*` significa Todos, se ele estiver seguido depois de algum outro elemento, o que for declarado sera interpretado para todos os elementos a partir de sua hierarquia.

Agora os elementos seguidos por `:` são já vários tipos de seletores possíveis.
existe o `:hover` que é para quando o cursor do mouse estiver em cima do elemento. `:visited` para quando o elemento que seja um link já tenha sido visitado. `:before` e `:after` que criam pseudo-elementos, `nth-child` e `nth-of-type` que selecionam posições de elementos. etc...

E além dos que você citou no exemplo, existem outros tipos de seletores: `~` `[prop=valor]` etc...

Caso queira saber mais sobre todos os seletores eu conselho este site:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Ele mostra todo e como usar :)

Espero que tenha ajudado!

Comment: Sensacional sua explicação, obrigado.

Answer (score 12):

**CSS**

No [site do Maujor](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/sintaxetut.php) tem um tutorial sobre CSS muito bom, vou deixar aqui algumas partes relevantes.

A regra CSS tem sua própria sintaxe e define como o estilo será aplicado aos elementos do HTML:

```
seletor { propriedade: valor; }
```

> - *seletor*: é um elemento da marcação `HTML` identificado pelo seu nome (por exemplo: `<p>`, `<h1>`, `<form>`), pelo nome de uma classe
>     aplicada ao elemento da marcação `HTML` (por exemplo: `.topo`,
>     `.principal`, `.menu`), pelo nome de um identificador ID aplicado ao
>     elemento da marcação `HTML` (por exemplo: `#tudo`, `#auxiliar`,
>     `#rodape`) ou por qualquer outro identificador `CSS` de elementos ou
>     trechos da marcação `HTML`, genericamente denominados de seletores
>     `CSS`.
> - *propriedade*: é a propriedade do elemento `HTML` ao qual será aplicada a estilização definida no valor (por exemplo: tamanho da
>     fonte, cor do texto, altura do elemento).
> - *valor*: é a característica específica a ser assumida pela propriedade (por exemplo: letra tipo arial, cor azul, fundo verde,
>     altura igual a 300px)
>
> Na sintaxe de uma regra `CSS`, escreve-se o seletor e a seguir a
>   propriedade e o valor separados por dois pontos e colocados entre
>   chaves `{` `}`.
>
> É possível escrever mais de uma declaração `CSS` em uma regra com o
>   objetivo de estilizar-se várias propriedades de um mesmo seletor.
>   Neste caso deve-se usar ponto-e-vírgula (`;`) para separar as
>   declarações `CSS` constantes da regra `CSS`. O ponto-e-vírgula é
>   facultativo quando a regra `CSS`for constituída de uma só declaração
>   `CSS`e também facultativo após a última declaração `CSS`quando houver
>   mais de uma declaração `CSS`.

**Agrupamento de Seletores**

A regra será aplicada a mais de um seletor, basta utilizar a vírgula(`,`).

```
h1, h2, p, .box {
    color: green;
}
```

**Seletor classe**
Você pode criar uma regra para uma classe específica e colocá-la no HTML como o atributo `class`. No seu código CSS, utilize o nome da sua classe  precedido de ponto(`.`):

```
elemento.nomedaclasse { 
    propriedade: valor;
}
```

**Seletor ID**

> A grande diferença entre o seletor **id** e o de classe é a unicidade.
>   Ou seja, um seletor *id* de determinado nome só pode ser definido a um
>   e somente um elemento `HTML` dentro do documento.

É a mesma ideia da classe, porém o `id` é precedido do `#` ("cerquilha"/"tralha"/"jogo-da-velha"):

```
#meuID {
    propriedade: valor;
}
```

**Inserindo comentários nas CSS**

Comentários em CSS começam com o sinal `/*` e termina com `*/`:

```
/* este é um comentário*/
p { 
font-size: 14px;               /* este é outro comentário*/
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial, Serif;
}
```

**No seu exemplo**:

- `.e1{}`: estilo será aplicado na classe `.e1`
- `#e1{}`: estilo será aplicado no id `#e1`
- `e1 e2{}`: o estilo será aplicado dentro do elemento `e2` que está dentro de `e1`, vou te dar um exemplo:

  - Suponha que `e1` seja a `table` e `e2` a `td`, que tem a classe `padrao`:

    `.table td.padrao {
       font-size: 10pt;
       color: red;
    }`

    - Todas as `td`, que tiverem a classe `padrao`, da `table` terão tamanho da fonte `10pt` e cor vermelha.

- `e1,e2{}`: aplica o estilo nos dois.
- `e1 *{}`: aplica o estilo para todos os elementos dentro de `e1`,
- `e1{}`: aplica o estilo no `e1`, um exemplo seria o `body`:

  `body {
          min-width: 650px;
     }`

- `.e1 a:link{}` = olha o exemplo, ele "muda" o estilo de um link quando você passa o mouse sobre ele:

  `a:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
    }`

Referência:

- [Tutorial CSS](http://www.maujor.com/w3ctuto/firstcss.html)
- [Sintaxe CSS](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/sintaxetut.php)

Answer (score 6):

Cada método de definição implica diretamente como o estilo é atribuído ao elemento, classe ou id em seu HTML.

Possuímos 4 seletores principais, que são:

- Elemento: São elementos nativos do HTML. Ex.: p, li, ul, h1, div, etc...
- ID: Definido com prefixo `#` antes do seu nome. Ex.: #minhaId, #umEstilo, etc...
- Classe: Definido com prefixo `.`. Ex.: .minhaClasse, .meuEstilo, etc...
- Pseudo-Selector: São elementos HTML que podemos obter mas que não podemos definir manualmente no HTML. Por exemplo, eu posso selecionar o segundo elemento usando `'elemento':nth-child(2)`, mas eu não consigo criar esse elemento em meu HTML.

Veja o exemplo:

```css
div {
    color: blue;
}

#sublinhado {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.negrito {
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul li:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Elemento: Texto em cor azul</div>

<div id="sublinhado">ID: Texto azul e sublinhado</div>


<div class="negrito">Classe: Texto azul e em negrito</div>

<ul>
    <li>Pseudo: Primeiro - normal</li>
    <li>Pseudo: Segundo - cor vermelha</li>
<ul>
```

---

Portanto, a ordem que eles são declarados interfere no resultado final levando em consideração sua estrutura HTML.

Por exemplo, definições separadas por vírgulas irão aplicar os mesmos atributos a diferentes seletores.

```
h1, #meuId, .minhaClasse, p:nth-child(3) {
    color: pink;
}
```

Neste caso, todos esses seletores terão a cor rosa.

Para uma leitura mais aprofundada nisso, recomendo essa leitura: https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 3):

O **.** é o elemento que contém class="" ... Quando utilizamos class="" no HTML então no CSS chamamos o elemento com **.** (ponto), exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<div class="fundo-vermelho">Aqui vai ser um fundo vermelho colocado via class</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fundo-vermelho{
    background:red;
}
```

Com # (cerquilha/jogo da velha) é a mesma coisa só que se aplica a **ID**. Quando no HTML usamos **id** então no CSS usamos **#**

**HTML**

```
<div id="fundo-azul">Aqui vai ser um fundo azul colocado via ID</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fundo-azul{
    background:blue;
}
```

Quando usamos 2 elementos seguindos como **e1 e2** quer dizer que vamos aplicar o comando CSS dentro do elemento **e2** que está dentro de **e1**

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="conteudo">
       Esse é o conteúdo
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box .conteudo{
    font-weight:bold;
    background:pink
}
```

Quando separamos o elemento por vírgula, quer dizer que os estilo que estamos aplicando a um vamos aplicar também para o outro

**HTML**

```
<div id="elemento1">Elemento 1</div>
<div class="elemento2">Elemento 2</div>
<div id="elemento3">Elemento 3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#elemento1, .elemento2, #elemento3{
    background:red;
}
```

Quando se usa o **elemento *** então vamos aplicar todo o estilo a todos elementos dentro do **elemento**

Quando não utilizamos **.** ou **#** só definimos o nome do **elemento** então só pode ser que o estilo seja atribuido a **tags**

**HTML**

```
<a href="">Aqui vai ser um fundo vermelho colocado via class</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a{
    background:purple;
}
```

E quando utilizamos algo como **:hover** (pseudo-elementos) são para aplicar o estilo em partes especificas do elemento. Vou dar um exemplo do link (`<a>`)

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="meu-link">Passe o mouse aqui</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#meu-link:hover{
    background:red;
}
```

Os pseudo-elementos são itens especificos, ou seja, não pode ser qualquer nome.

Answer (score 1):

**Vou dar uma explicação da maneira que eu entendo**

`.e1{}`- Quando usado o ponto antes de alguma propriedade, quer dizer que será aplicado em todas as classes com esse nome.

`#e1{}` - Quando temos um Jogo da Velha/Cerquilha/Hashtag indica que o estilo a seguir será aplicado no elemento com o ID `e1`.

`e1 e2{}` - Não me lembro muito bem, vou procurar e volto a postar quando descobrir.

`e1, e2{}` - Aplica o estilo as propriedades com a seguinte tag, no caso e1 e e2. isso para resumir seu código, assim não tendo duplicidade de estilos para tags diferentes.

`e1 *{}` - Aplica o estilo para todos os elementos dentro de `e1`.

`e1{}` - Todos os elementos `e1` terão o estilo definido.

`.e1 a:link{}` - Todos os Elementos que contem a classe `e1` e possuem uma propriedade a com um href.

Segue um link aonde você encontra todos os [Seletores do CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) no qual você pode se orientar melhor.