# Seletor no CSS diferenças

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, layout-responsivo

Qual a diferença entre:

```
.figure-box>figure>img{
    width: 440px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Para:

```
.figure-box figure img{
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz uma pergunta sobre seletores, e uma das duvidas era isto, [veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194920/como-funcionam-os-seletores-no-css3).

Comment: [Relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155712/qual-a-defini%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-cada-combina%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-seletores-css)

Answer (score 0):

`.A>.B>.C` selecionará C que é filho imediato de B que é filho imediato de A

`.A .B .C` selecionará C e B para qualquer descendência

Answer (score 0):

A diferença é que com o `>` significa que o elemente tem que ser filho direto, por ex:

```
<div class="figure-box">
   <div><div><div><div>
      <figure>
         <div>
            <img src=""/>
         </div>
      </figure>
   </div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Para esse trexo de HTML, o `.figure-box figure img`, mas o `.figure-box > figure > img`, pois o `figure` não é filho direto do `.figure-box`

E para seletor sem `>`, essa condição de **filho direto** é independente