# Por que algumas classes iniciam com pontos e outras não?

Tags: css, aplicação-web, classes

No CSS, quando defino a classe h2, por exemplo, ela não se inicia com ponto:

> h2 { color: red; }

Mas, outras classes, precisam do ponto:

> .texto-vermelho { color:red; }

Por que isto ocorre?

Comment: Respondido em [Qual a definição de cada combinação de Seletores css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155712/qual-a-defini%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-cada-combina%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-seletores-css)

Comment: @Bacco quando é assim, é melhor responder ou deixa o usuário consultar a resposta antiga, pois essa será apagada?

Comment: Sem o ponto vc está aplicando a um elemento html **h2** diretamente e não necessariamente a classe

Comment: @hugocsl o ideal é votar pelo fechamento por duplicata (se tiver pontuação suficiente), pois essa aqui vira link pra original. Se tiver algo a acrescentar, compensa postar mais uma resposta na original também, em vez dessa aqui.